# Using CakeDC's search plugin to search data with multi-select field

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.5, cakephp-search-plugin

I am trying to implement a search with CakeDC's Search [plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/search). In this search I have a field which has `'multiple' => 'checkbox'` is set. This field allows user to select multiple cities so that they can filter results according to city/cities. What I did in favour to this, I simply specified the `'type' => 'IN'` for that field in `Searchable` `Model`'s `$filterArgs`. But noting happened it just responded with all result no searching/filtration happened. To get the clear picture of what I have implemented here are the code snippets:

**Model.php**

```
   public $actsAs = array(
            'Search.Searchable'
        );
   public $filterArgs = array(
                    'city' => array(
                        'type' => 'in',
                        'field' => 'Model.city'
                    ));
```

**search_form.ctp**

```
echo $this->Form->create('Model', array('url' => array('controller' => 'models', 'action' => 'search')));
echo $this->Form->input('city', array(
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => array(
        'city1' => 'city1',
        'city2' => 'city2',
        'cityn' => 'cityn')
));
echo $this->Form->end('search');
```

**ModelsController.php**

```
public function search() {
        $this->layout = 'front_common';
        $this->Prg->commonProcess();
        $this->Paginator->settings = array(
            'conditions' => $this->Model->parseCriteria($this->Prg->parsedParams()),
            'limit' => 10
        );
        $this->set('Data', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

also once I tried to use a `beforeFilter()` in `ModelsController` to implode the `city` `array()` with `(,)` to be used with `IN` but same all results. I want to ask if there is any other plugin to do this or any hack to do this with cakeDC's search plugin. Please help.

Comment: I don't think this functionality is supported by the Search plugin. You'd probably be better off just building your own filtering.

Comment: @DavidYell yes it is not there I think. may be we would need to tweak it to use it as we want it or can you suggest any method so that I can implement it..?

Comment: Personally I'd probably just loop through the request data and build an array which I could pass to an 'IN' condition in my query.

Comment: @DavidYell yes I did something like that, I have mentioned that too at last in question may be my implementation was wrong..

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, assuming you are passing in the arg to `parseCriteria()` as a simple array of values.

```
public $filterArgs = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'city',
        'type' => 'value',
        'field' => 'Model.city'
    )
);
```

And you should be able to pass `city:houston|dallas|austin` in the URL

It should parse that into an array of `args => [city => [houston, dallas, austin]]`

And `parseCriteria()` will translate that into the following conditions fragment: `[Model.city => [houston, dallas, austin]]`

And CakePHP natively translates that into a SQL where fragment: `IN(houston, dallas, austin)`

Use DebugKit and monitor your SQL... you can `debug()` at any step of the process, you should get these values.

Here's the full docs on the Search plugin:
https://github.com/CakeDC/search/tree/master/Docs/Documentation

*(I use it heavily, and I love how it lets me organize all search filters)*